# HTML adding an if statement to <option><select>

Tags: php, html

I have an image uploader and I'm trying to make the site display what type of option has been selected when the file is uploaded. I will later add this functionality to connect to different tables in a database, but for now I just want it printing out what option has been selected.

Here is my upload. html:

```
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="400000" />
Choose a file to upload:
<br />
<br />
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
<br />
<select name = "uploadType">
<option value="Picture">Picture</option>
<option value="Video">Video</option>
<option value="Fact">Fact</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
```

And here is my uploader. php:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";

if (uploadType == "Picture"){
echo "\nYou have uploaded a picture.";

} if (uploadType == "Video"){
echo "\nYou have uploaded a video.";
} if (uploadType == "Fact"){
echo "\nYou have uploaded a fact.";
} else{
echo "\nuploadType fail!";
}

} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Every time I try to upload it just comes up with the "uploadType fail!" message. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you so much!

Comment: And that's why you turn on error reporting during development, because that would complain about an undefined constant "uploadType"...

Comment: Just a heads up `400000` is 400kb or just under 1/2 a megabyte, dont confuse it for 4mb or 40mb. `MAX_FILE_SIZE` is in bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$uploadType = $_POST["uploadType"];
```

Then use `$uploadType` in your if statements. Variables in PHP always begin with a dollar sign.

In addition, use `else if` for the other conditions.

Comment: Works great, I should have known, I just wasn't sure on the exact syntax. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two 'else' statements - before the video and before the fact 'if' statement.

Comment: Unless you choose "Fact", the fail message will always appear.

Answer (score 0):

`uploadType` is being used as a constant here. Try replacing `uploadType` with `$_POST['uploadType']`.